# empty maven project using alfresco sdk

Tags: maven, alfresco

When I trying create empty maven project using alfresco sdk:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml -Dfilter=org.alfresco.maven.archetype
```

I get an error:

> archetypeCatalog
>   'https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml'
>   is not supported anymore. Please read the plugin documentation for
>   details.

please tell me how can I fix this!!!

Comment: You might be interested in working through my Alfresco Maven SDK tutorial: https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong command. if you don't see the menu for creating the archetype, check firewall settings.

use the below command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.alfresco:
```